# IL Emit Disconnected Context Error

Tags: c#, reflection, reflection.emit

I'm trying to make a setter in IL emit, but this setter must only accept objects which are not null, if not, it must throw an exception.
This is my class Notnull which recieves a il Generator and a FieldBuilder in which the setter (if not null) must store its value.

```
 public class NonNull 
{
    public void CreateIL(ILGenerator il, FieldBuilder field)
    {
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);        // Push "this" on the stack

        il.Emit(OpCodes.Newobj, typeof(Utils).GetConstructor(new Type[] { }));
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc_1);

        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc_2);

        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_2);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_1);        // Push "value" on the stack
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt,typeof(Utils).GetMethod("checkIfNull"));
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Pop);

        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_2);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Stfld, field);   // Set the field "_Name" to "value"
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
    }
}
```

Class utils which I call in the IL and throws my exception.

```
class Utils
    {
        public void checkIfNull(object obj)
        {
            if (obj == null) throw new MyException();
        }
    }
```

When I try to create my new type (which has this IL) it presents a Disconnected context error.

Comment: Could you post the full error? And assuming it's an exception, including its stack trace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making it way more complicated than it needs to be by using non-static methods. If an object reference is not required to call the method, the method should always be static.

This is essentially what you're trying to emit now:

```
public string Name
{
    set
    {
        Utils u = new Utils();
        string s = value;
        u.checkIfNull(s);
        _Name = s;
    }
}
```

There is absolutely no need to create an instance of `Utils` class to do the check.

Start by making `checkIfNull()` static:

```
static class Utils
{
    public static void checkIfNull(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null) throw new MyException();
    }
}
```

Here's what you should be trying to emit:

```
public string Name
{
    set
    {
        Utils.checkIfNull(value);
        _Name = value;
    }
}
```

And here's how:

```
public class NonNull 
{
    public static void CreateIL(ILGenerator il, FieldBuilder field)
    {
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1); // Push "value" on the stack
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Call, typeof(Utils).GetMethod("checkIfNull"));
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Stfld, field);   // Set the field "_Name" to "value"
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick answer! I see now that I was in fact complicating my set method. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand exactly what you want to do (with the NotNull class and the FieldBuilder), but I can show you what IL you need for your setter property (check for null and set field).

If it work for you, great. And if not, let me know the problem and we will fix it.

First lets describe what we want.

1. Create `Utils` class
2. Load `value` arg
3. Call `checkIfNull`
4. Load `this`
5. Load `value`
6. Set field
7. Ret

The emit will be something like this:

```
il.Emit(OpCodes.Newobj, typeof(Utils).GetConstructor(new Type[] { }));
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt,typeof(Utils).GetMethod("checkIfNull"));
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Stfld, field);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
```

And the result need to look like this:

```
newobj instance void MyApplication.Utils::.ctor() //create `Utils` object
ldarg.1                                           //load `value`
callvirt instance void 
         MyApplication.Utils::checkIfNull(object) //call checkForNull
ldarg.0                                           //load `this`
ldarg.1                                           //load `value`
stfld int32 MyApplication.Program::_field         //store `value` in `_field`
ret
```

Comment: No need to create instance of `Utils` class. `checkIfNull` should be static. See my answer.

Comment: @MrAnderson "No need" is depend on the question owner. I saw your answer and sure it can be just fine. (Nice that you remember to emit `call` when its static). I just answer on what he ask.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I'm just trying to help the OP because maybe he does not understand static methods, as this would be the place to use them.